# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-modal

Im trying open a modal in my principal component, but i have this problem when a try to call function `abrirModal()`:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'abrirModal')**

button in my principal component:
`cotacaooffline.component.html:`

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-blue btn-block" 
                (click)="openModalEbao()">
               Text
</button>
```

TS `cotaçãooffline.component:`

```
import {ModalAlterarEbaoComponent} from 'src/app/components/modals/modal-alterar-ebao/modal-alterar-ebao.component'
 

export class CotacaoofflineComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
 
  @ViewChild(ModalAlterarEbaoComponent) modalAlterarEbaoComponent: ModalAlterarEbaoComponent;
  
  ...others @ViewChild }
  
  
    openModalEbao(){
    this.modalAlterarEbaoComponent.abrirModal();
  }
```

`ModalAlterarEbaoComponent:`

```
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
@ViewChild('modalEbao', {static: false})
  modalEbao: ModalDirective;
  
 
  abrirModal() {
    this.modalEbao.show();
  }
```

`ModaDirective` File:

```
import { ComponentRef, ElementRef, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, OnInit, Renderer2, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalBackdropComponent } from './modal-backdrop.component';
import { ModalOptions } from './modal-options.class';
import { ComponentLoaderFactory } from 'ngx-bootstrap/component-loader';
/** Mark any code with directive to show it's content in modal */
import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
export declare class ModalDirective implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
    private _element;
    private _renderer;
    /** allows to set modal configuration via element property */
    set config(conf: ModalOptions);
    get config(): ModalOptions;
    /** This event fires immediately when the `show` instance method is called. */
    onShow: EventEmitter<ModalDirective>;
    /** This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user
     * (will wait for CSS transitions to complete)
     */
    onShown: EventEmitter<ModalDirective>;
    /** This event is fired immediately when
     * the hide instance method has been called.
     */
    onHide: EventEmitter<ModalDirective>;
    /** This event is fired when the modal has finished being
     * hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).
     */
    onHidden: EventEmitter<ModalDirective>;
    /** This field contains last dismiss reason.
     * Possible values: `backdrop-click`, `esc` and `id: number`
     * (if modal was closed by direct call of `.hide()`).
     */
    dismissReason: string;
    get isShown(): boolean;
    protected _config: ModalOptions;
    protected _isShown: boolean;
    protected isBodyOverflowing: boolean;
    protected originalBodyPadding: number;
    protected scrollbarWidth: number;
    protected timerHideModal: number;
    protected timerRmBackDrop: number;
    protected backdrop: ComponentRef<ModalBackdropComponent>;
    private _backdrop;
    private isNested;
    private clickStartedInContent;
    constructor(_element: ElementRef, _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, _renderer: Renderer2, clf: ComponentLoaderFactory, modalDefaultOption: ModalOptions);
    onClickStarted(event: MouseEvent): void;
    onClickStop(event: MouseEvent): void;
    onEsc(event: KeyboardEvent): void;
    ngOnDestroy(): void;
    ngOnInit(): void;
    /** Allows to manually toggle modal visibility */
    toggle(): void;
    /** Allows to manually open modal */
    show(): void;
    /** Allows to manually close modal */
    hide(event?: Event): void;
    /** Private methods @internal */
    protected getConfig(config?: ModalOptions): ModalOptions;
    /**
     *  Show dialog
     *  @internal
     */
    protected showElement(): void;
    /** @internal */
    protected hideModal(): void;
    /** @internal */
    protected showBackdrop(callback?: Function): void;
    /** @internal */
    protected removeBackdrop(): void;
    /** Events tricks */
    protected focusOtherModal(): void;
    /** @internal */
    protected resetAdjustments(): void;
    /** Scroll bar tricks */
    /** @internal */
    protected checkScrollbar(): void;
    protected setScrollbar(): void;
    protected resetScrollbar(): void;
    protected getScrollbarWidth(): number;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ModalDirective, [null, null, null, null, { optional: true; }]>;
    static ɵdir: ɵngcc0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<ModalDirective, "[bsModal]", ["bs-modal"], { "config": "config"; }, { "onShow": "onShow"; "onShown": "onShown"; "onHide": "onHide"; "onHidden": "onHidden"; }, never>;
}

//# sourceMappingURL=modal.directive.d.ts.map
```

Any help is welcome :) tks!

Comment: You haven't actually defined what the show function does. It's like an interface in this usage.

Comment: Where is `openModalEbao()` called?